# NestJs + mongoose ClassSerializerInterceptors not working

Tags: mongoose, nestjs

I have a project in nestJs, with mongosee, and I want to exclude certain properties from returned object.
Specifically:

```
@Schema()
export class User {
  @Prop({type: String, required: true, unique: true, index:true})
  email: string;

  @Prop({type: String, required: true})
  username: string;

  @Prop({type: String, required: true, unique: true, index:true})
  handle: string;

  @Prop({type: String, required: true})
  @Exclude({ toPlainOnly: true })
  password: string;

  @Prop({type: String, default: () => randomBytes(16).toString('hex')})
  @Exclude({ toPlainOnly: true })
  emailVerifCode: string;

  //other properties
}
```

And when I try this:

```
  @Post('login')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuardLocal)
  @UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
  async login(@CurrentUser() user: User) {

    return {
      user: user,
      token: await this.authService.getTokenForUser(user)
    }
  }
```

I get returned an empty object. I also tried adding:

```
app.useGlobalInterceptors(
    new ClassSerializerInterceptor(app.get(Reflector))
  );
```

All controllers I tried with ClassSerializerInterceptor returns an empty object.

To the main.ts but I get again an empty object as a response.
I tried other solutions but none worked. Getting kind of desperate at this point.

Using:
"mongoose": "^7.5.2",
"@nestjs/core": "^10.0.0"

Answer (score 0):

Doing so just won't work.
If you go here, https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/serialization

You should see a red notice:
`Note that we must return an instance of the class. If you return a plain JavaScript object, for example, { user: new UserEntity() }, the object won't be properly serialized.`

Well that actually means that your controller must return a class instance, meaning: `return new User(...)`.

In your case there is also a token in the response, which isn't a property of your  `User` class and this is the problem. Your only option here is to make it one so you could return an instance class.

Comment: Even if I try:
  `/**
  * Logs in with username and password
  * @param { string } username
  * @param { string } password
  * @returns { Promise<User>} returns user and bearerToken 
  */
  @Post('login')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuardLocal)
  @UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
  async login(@CurrentUser() user: User) {

    return user
  }`
And return a plain user Object I get an empty response.

Comment: @SimoneProvenzano try return explicitly instance of the object, `new User(...)`